# How to make use of custom jar in Synapse Notebook after uploading it in Azure Synapse Workspace?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-notebook, azure-notebooks, azure-synapse-analytics

I am trying to add my customized jar in Azure Synapse Workspace to make use of user defined function (udf) present in the jar while running the sql query in Synapse Notebook.

An Example: There is udf named as MapCloud() registered in UDFHelper.scala file inside the jar. I uploaded my jar (app-assembly-synapse.jar) to Azure Synapse Workspace and then added package to one of my spark pool (Everything2). But when I tried to build a session, the session was getting killed, not sure why.

Questions:

1. How can I create a session after adding package to my spark pool.
2. How can I make use of udf after the session is getting created.

What I tried:
I was able to upload my jar in Workspace
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QBKN.png)

I added the package to my spark pool
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTfjp.png)

I tried to create session but got failed with the error
[Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBZo3.png)

When I try to execute this
[Screenshot4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G3fD.png),
I am getting below error =>
AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'MapCloud'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 3 pos 7

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!